# Не работает локально javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь подключить на сайт галерею на jquery, но, после загрузки страницы ничего не происходит. Вот подключение скриптов:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.transit.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.slideshowify.min.js"></script>
```

Вот запуск скрипта:

```
<script>$('img').slideshowify();</script>
```

Тестирую сайт локально. При тестировании кода через http://plnkr.co/ все работает. В чем может быть проблема?
Вот весь html код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <title></title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <link href="css/style_main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  media="screen"/>
        <!-- Подключение js и слайд шоу -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.transit.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.slideshowify.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Подключение js и слайд шоу -->
</head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <header class="header">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="logo"></div>
        </a>
        <?php include_once 'menu.html';?>

    </header><!-- .header-->

    <main class="content">
        <?php

            switch($_GET['menu']) {

            case 'main':
            include_once("main.php");
            break;

            case 'contacts':
            include_once("contacts.php");
            break;

            case 'portfolio':
            include_once("portfolio.php");
            break;

            case 'service':
            include_once("sservice.php");
            break;

            case 'digest':
            include_once("digest.php");
            break;

            case 'about_us':
            include_once("about_us.php");
            break;

            default:
            include_once("main.php");
            break;
            }
        ?>  
        <div id="imgContainer">
            <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7207/6917838169_dcf0e2fdd4_o.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/alekbiotic/5484_9.eifel_tower_1.JPG"/>
            <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/libbytish/25966_9.Roll4009.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/alekbiotic/55975_9.DSC_3208.jpg">
        </div>

        <script>$('img').slideshowify();</script>
    </main><!-- .content -->

</div><!-- .wrapper -->

<footer class="footer">

</footer><!-- .footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Тот же код, только через песочницу:[пример](http://plnkr.co/edit/OLPtvwdAPpUSogcUoKKx?p=preview)

Comment: А в консоли что-нибудь есть?

Comment: а так? `<script>
    $(function () {
    $('img').slideshowify()
});
</script>`

Comment: да, в консоли выводит вот такую ошибку:`TypeError: $(...).slideshowify is not a function`

Comment: Попробуйте скачать jQuery себе в папку с проектом. Возможно проблемы с доступом во внешнюю библиотеку

Comment: пробовал скачивать, результат тот же

Comment: неправильный путь к библиотекам локальным скорее всего.

Comment: если бы что то было с путями то тогда бы на http://plnkr.co/ этот же код не работал был?

Comment: @Вадим вы просто не то выбираете для слайд шоу, скорее всего там должен быть блок, в котором есть картинки, а не все картинки на которые вы вешаете `.slideshowify` посмотрите примеры того, как объявляется скрипт в примерах у разработчика

Comment: @ Василий Барбашев, у меня на сайте есть, для теста, только 4 изображения (тег img) они отделены одним блоком: 
`<div id="imgContainer">
   <img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7207/6917838169_dcf0e2fdd4_o.jpg"/>
   <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/alekbiotic/5484_9.eifel_tower_1.JPG"/>
   <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/libbytish/25966_9.Roll4009.jpg"/>
   <img src="http://img.gallerama.com/users/alekbiotic/55975_9.DSC_3208.jpg">
  </div>`

Comment: вот этот блок и вставьте в `$('#imgContainer').slideshowify()`. Ну попробуйте, т.к. никто не вешает скрипты на `img`

Comment: @Василий Барбашев, я делал все по инструкции автора данного скрипта. Попробовал предложенный вами вариант, не работает.

Comment: @Вадим весь ваш текущий код добавьте в вопрос, сейчас посмотрю

Comment: @Вадим и где же мой код из второго комментария? И да, явно у вас скрипт не загружается на страницу, это и вызывает ошибку

Answer (score 3):

Разобрался, проблема была в том что в одном из подключаемых файлов был уже подключен jquery другой версии, и был конфликт.

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из ошибки

> `TypeError: $(...).slideshowify is not a function`

очевидно у вас плагин slideshowify не загружен.  Убедитесь, что в html коде есть вот такое:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.slideshowify.js"></script>
```

(естественно, с необходимыми директориями, версиями итд).  Если есть, то убедитесь, что вы не получаете 404 на последнем из этих файлов.

Внимательно прочитайте раздел Usage на [сайте slideshowify](http://www.subchild.com/slideshowify/).

Comment: Через консоль проверил, эти файлы при загрузке не выдают 404

Comment: Попробуйте просто открыть в браузере jquery.slideshowify.js - c директориями, как в этом таге - убедитесь, что открывается и содержит правильную инфу.

Comment: попробовал, файлы открываются как положено